# Data Table Gateway - one class per database?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I have read Martin Fowlers book (Patterns of Enterprise Architecture).  There are a number of patterns for accessing the data layer:

Table Data Gateway (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)
Row Data Gateway (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html)
Active record (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

The emphasis of these patterns is to have one class in the application per table.

I am developing an application that connects to multiple databases for search purposes.  There are only a few queries per database.

Is there a design pattern that has one class per database i.e. all the SQL for the database is contained in one class.  This is what I am planning to do but it would help with documentation if there was such a design pattern.  Perhaps I am overthinking this?

Comment: I think if you look at some of GoF's design patterns, perhaps some of them such as [*Bridge*](http://www.oodesign.com/bridge-pattern.html) and [*Abstract Factory*](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html) might help you achieve what you want.

Comment: As much as I love and respect M. Fowler's work, I think all of this falls flat on its face when compared to the simplicity, ease of development and cleanliness of code brought about by an ORM such as Entity Framework.